# SASS Ampersand – Chaining CSS class with the parent selector '&' like in LESS

Tags: css, sass, less

### LESS (CSS)

[see in action](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.app%7B%5Cn%20%20%23page%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.inner%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20.left%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26.padding-left-10px%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding-left%3A%2010px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20rtl%20direction%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.rtl%26%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding-left%3A%200%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding-right%3A%2010px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)

```
.app {
  #page {
    .inner {
      .left {
        &.padding-left-10px {
          padding-left: 10px;

          // rtl direction
          .rtl& {  //////////////////////////////////
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 10px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Consider the line I have highlighted with `///....`.

I want the same result in SASS (.scss). Is it possible?

**Expected result should be:**

```
.rtl.app #page .inner .left.padding-left-10px {}
```

and not

```
.rtl .app #page .inner .left.padding-left-10px {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: put a space between `.rtl` and `&`.  `.rtl & {`  The ampersand is a literal string concatenation

Comment: @ntgCleaner, did you see the line before **Thanks.** in description? I want `.rtl.app` output in Sass with the same herarchy.

Comment: Sorry, I read the expected and "and not" the opposite!  Looking into it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to use the LESS feature where you can [change the order of the selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order) by using the parent selector. It isn't working as expected because that specific LESS feature isn't implemented the same way in SASS.

If you want the equivalent output code in SASS, then you can use the [`@at-root` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) in order to scope the selector to the root. Then you would also need to use [variable interpolation](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) (i.e., `.rtl#{&}`) for the parent selector:

```
.app {
  #page {
    .inner {
      .left {
        &.padding-left-10px {
          padding-left: 10px;

          @at-root {
            .rtl#{&} {
              padding-left: 0;
              padding-right: 10px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which would compile to:

```
.app #page .inner .left.padding-left-10px {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.rtl.app #page .inner .left.padding-left-10px {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh for quick answer. Let me try with this.

Comment: Thanks a tonne @Josh. This works for me. But I am still looking for a way without `@at-root` directive...

Answer (score 0):

Josh gave you an answer which will work, i guess. But I still wanna give you some advice and that is look into [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/), or someway. Nesting like this is really unnecessary.

Your code could be better for readability.

For example:

```
.padding {
     padding: 10px;
 }

 .padding--left { // This is a modifier for padding
     padding: 0 0 0 10px;
 }

 .padding--right { // This is a modifier for padding
     padding: 0 10px 0 0;
 }

 <div class="padding padding--left">Using it in a div</div>
```

You don't have to follow all the rules which are defined in BEM, but some are really nice to use.

Comment: your comment make sense and really appreciate your advice. But sometime we don't have control over the HTML structure and to overwrite CSS through specificity, we have to follow deeper hierarchy.

Comment: Just a note that this can be written as `.padding { &#{&}--left { ... } }` etc